# Name the generalization of regular tetrahedron in higher dimension

Tags: geometry, terminology, 3d

By a regular tetrahedron, I’m referring to the tetrahedron formed by connecting the vertices of the $3$-simplex with the “far corner” $(1, 1, 1)$.
That is, the four vertices of this regular tetrahedron are $(1, 0, 0) ,\, (0, 1, 0) ,\, (0, 0, 1)$, and $(1, 1, 1)$, shown as blue edges one on the right.

**My question is this:**

> What do you call the counterpart (generalization) of such tetrahedron in higher dimensions?

That is, connect the vertices of the $n$-simplex with the "far corner" $(1, 1, 1,\ldots 1)$ so that one gets a shape which vertices are the unit vectors $e_i$ and $\sum e_i$, and the sides have the same length $\sqrt{n-1}$.

**If there's not a name for such construction**, how about alternatively connect the origin $(0, 0, 0)$ with $(0, 1, 1) ,\, (1, 0, 1) ,\, (1, 1, 0)$?

This alternative tetrahedron is shown below with orange edges. One can compare it with the previous one involving the simplex with blue edges.

[image]

The higher dimension counterpart of the orange tetrahedron has vertices being the complement (binary flip) of that from the blue one, e.g. $(0,1,0,\ldots, 0) \to (1,0,1,\ldots, 1)$. It is congruent to the previous one, also with side length $\sqrt{n-1}$.

Comment: You are probably looking for a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

Comment: @robjohn ha, thanks, I just wasn't sure about the terminology.

Comment: They can be called *regular simplices* (plural of simplex). The orientation is irrelevant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you. Just to make sure: previously I thought a regular simplex is one that is sort of orthogonal, like sitting in the corner of a Cartesian coordinates. In fact, regular simplex refers to the fact that the side lengths are all the same, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting to remove this question from the unanswered list, and I'll check it as soon as the system restriction is lifted.

I previously thought $n$-simplex (as I used it in the question) refers to only the "orthogonal" ones.

Yeah the very first few sentences in e.g. wiki for simplex states clearly that a $n$-simplex refers to generally a convex hull formed by its $n+1$ vertices.

I guess there's no special names for the special cases I talked about in the question.